# How to detect three consecutive days in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have DataFrame with index in Datetime format. I need to keep the days which are adjacent to at least 2 additional days (I mean 3 consecutive days should come together). Please, share your solution.

For example,

```
Date
2021.11.08 #<-
2021.11.09 #<-
2021.11.10 #<-
2021.11.12
2021.11.13
2021.11.16 #<-
2021.11.17 #<-
2021.11.18 #<-
2021.11.19 #<-
2021.11.22
2021.11.23
```

<- to be selected

Answer (score 4):

Try with `groupby`:

```
#reset index if "Date" is the index and not a column
#df = df.reset_index()

#convert to datetime
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%Y.%m.%d")

#check if adjacent rows are 1 day apart
adjacent = df["Date"].diff().dt.days.fillna(1).eq(1)

#get sequences with a minimum length of 3
mask = df.groupby(adjacent.ne(adjacent.shift()).cumsum())["Date"].transform('count').ge(3)
output = df[mask|mask.shift(-1)]

>>> output
        Date
0 2021-11-08
1 2021-11-09
2 2021-11-10
5 2021-11-16
6 2021-11-17
7 2021-11-18
8 2021-11-19
```

Answer (score 2):

With `groupby` `filter`

```
oneday = pd.offsets.Day(1)
diff = df.Date.diff().bfill()

df.groupby(
    diff.ne(oneday).cumsum()
).filter(lambda d: len(d) > 2)


        Date
0 2021-11-08
1 2021-11-09
2 2021-11-10
5 2021-11-16
6 2021-11-17
7 2021-11-18
8 2021-11-19
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'diff'. Date is index of dataframe and it is in datetime format.

Comment: then change the `diff` line to `diff = df.index.to_series().diff().bfill()`

Answer (score 1):

Using slicing with a mask:

```
N=3

# find start of groups
m = ~pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).diff().eq('1d')

# check size and keep if ≥ N
df[m.groupby(m.cumsum()).transform('size').ge(N)]
```

Output:

```
         Date
0  2021.11.08
1  2021.11.09
2  2021.11.10
5  2021.11.16
6  2021.11.17
7  2021.11.18
8  2021.11.19
```

###### keep every second element

```
N = 3
m = ~pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).diff().eq('1d')

g = m.groupby(m.cumsum())

m1 = g.transform('size').ge(N)
m2 = g.cumcount().mod(2) # odd lines

df[m1&m2]
```

Output:

```
         Date
1  2021.11.09
6  2021.11.17
8  2021.11.19
```

*NB. If you only want the second and not **every** second, use `eq(1)` in place of `mod(2)`*

Comment: AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'diff'. Date is index of dataframe and it is in datetime format.

Comment: @Artuk use `df.index.to_series()` in place of `df['Date']` then

Comment: May I ask also how can I pick  every second day only between consecutive days ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Artuk see update

Comment: It really became challenge. I made mistake, I meant every second day between 3 consecutive days. Thank you.

Comment: @Artuk isn't it what it is doing? Can you ensure your example is correct and describe the logic in a bit more details?

Comment: For instance, if you have ABCD as consecutive days you get ABC and BCD as 3 consecutive days and you should obtain B and C as second days of those consecutive days.